# How to do math operation for multiple csv files

Tags: powershell, csv

I have found this code:

```bsh
$csv = Import-Csv D:\ExcelFiles\ba.csv
$csvout = "D:\ExcelFiles\bas.csv"

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    # Do the math
    $_.result = [math]::round($_.A / $_.B, 0)
    # Output the object (which contains A, B and result)
    $_
} | Export-Csv $csvout -NoTypeInformation
```

As you can see it is only for imported csv file. How to do this operation for multi csv files?

Edit1:

I have use this code:

```bsh
$SourcePath = "D:\CsvFiles"

$CsvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -filter "*.csv"

foreach ($File in $CsvFiles)
{
 $OutFile = "D:\CsvFiles\" + "\" + $File.BaseName + "s" + $File.Extension

$File | ForEach-Object 
{

            $_.result = [math]::round($_.A / $_.B, 0)
            # Output the object (which contains A, B and result)
            $_
        } | Export-Csv $OutFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

But it asks:

```
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1

Supply values for the following parameters:
```

To prevent this, I changed the code like below (bracket position after the foreach object):

```bsh
$SourcePath = "D:\CsvFiles"

$CsvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -filter "*.csv"

foreach ($File in $CsvFiles)
{
 $OutFile = "D:\CsvFiles\" + "\" + $File.BaseName + "s" + $File.Extension

$File | ForEach-Object {

            $_.result = [math]::round($_.A / B, 0)
            # Output the object (which contains A, B and result)
            $_
        } | Export-Csv $OutFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

This time, I got this error:

> The property 'result' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Thanks.

Comment: Are all the csv files in the same directory? What have you tried? Have you considering wrapping the above in a further `foreach` loop?

Comment: Note that this is 'banker's rounding'.  Odd numbers round up and event numbers round down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `Get-ChildItem` returns FileInfo and/or DirectoryInfo objects, so I would advise to add the `-File` switch to it so you know you're only dealing with files.

Then, you iterate through those files and in that loop you are doing something very strange, namely `$File | ForEach-Object`. Variable `$File` here contains a single FileInfo object, not the **imported data** of that file.

The question does not state if all files actually have a column called `result`, so the code should check for that, and lastly, remember that whatever you import from a CSV is a **string**. To do math on it you need to convert to a numeric data type.
The code below uses a simple cast to `[double]` for that.

```
$SourcePath = "D:\CsvFiles"
$CsvFiles   = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Filter "*.csv" -File

$CsvFiles | ForEach-Object {
    # create an output filepath. Since you are filtering on '*.csv', we can hardcode the extension here
    $OutFile = Join-Path -Path $SourcePath -ChildPath ('{0}s.csv' -f $_.BaseName)

    # so you know what file you are creating
    Write-Host "Working on $OutFile" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    # import the data from the file ($_) and calculate
    Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName | ForEach-Object {
        # since you're doing math, the values in A and B need to be converted from string to numeric type
        $result = [Math]::Round([double]$_.A / [double]$_.B, 0)
        # if the csv does not contain a column 'result', create it
        if ($_.PSObject.Properties.Name -notcontains 'result') { 
            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'result' -Value $result 
        }
        else {
            $_.result = $result
        }
        # Output the object (which contains A, B and result)
        $_
    } | Export-Csv -Path $OutFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the files are in the same directory, the rest in the above is *exactly* as you want it:

```
$Directory = "D:\CSVFiles"

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory

foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $OutFile = $Directory + "\" + $File.BaseName + "s" + $File.Extension

    $File | ForEach-Object
        {
            $_.result = [math]::round($_.A / $_.B, 0)
            # Output the object (which contains A, B and result)
            $_
        } | Export-Csv $OutFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Of course, without sample files, this impossible to test.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I tried your code but it asks parameter. I edited and updated my question.

Comment: @echelon I ***assumed*** the rest of the code you had was correct (as I state in my answer). if the code you already had isn't working, that's a somewhat different question. i've only shown you how to use that against every file in a directory.